# When a constructor calls a helper function, should the helper mutate the object or return part of the object?

Tags: c#, constructor, comparative-review

I have a private method that is called from the constructor to instantiate a bunch of objects.

I can do it two ways.

```
    private Monster[,] createMonsters()
    {
        Monster[,] myMonsterArray = new Monster[8, 6];

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            myMonsterArray[0, i] = new Monster(SpriteFactory.getMonster1Sprite());
            myMonsterArray[1, i] = new Monster(SpriteFactory.getMonster2Sprite());
            myMonsterArray[2, i] = new Monster(SpriteFactory.getMonster3Sprite());
            myMonsterArray[3, i] = new Monster(SpriteFactory.getMonster1Sprite());
            myMonsterArray[4, i] = new Monster(SpriteFactory.getMonster2Sprite());
            myMonsterArray[5, i] = new Monster(SpriteFactory.getMonster3Sprite()); 
        }

        return myMonsterArray;
    }
```

called with

```
monsterArray = createMonsters();
```

or

```
    private void createMonsters()
    {
        monsterArray = new Monster[8, 6];

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            monsterArray[0, i] = new Monster(SpriteFactory.getMonster1Sprite());
            monsterArray[1, i] = new Monster(SpriteFactory.getMonster2Sprite());
            monsterArray[2, i] = new Monster(SpriteFactory.getMonster3Sprite());
            monsterArray[3, i] = new Monster(SpriteFactory.getMonster1Sprite());
            monsterArray[4, i] = new Monster(SpriteFactory.getMonster2Sprite());
            monsterArray[5, i] = new Monster(SpriteFactory.getMonster3Sprite()); 
        }


    }
```

called with

```
createMonsters();
```

Is either better or worse?

Comment: I was set off by the fact that you have *camelCase* method names, whereas I thought that they would be *PascalCase* in C#.

Comment: Huh is it? - I _had_ been noticing that the syntax was like that, in the API, and I wasn't sure why it was the case.

Comment: This is the first C# project I've worked on in a while, just to add it to my portfolio.

Answer (score 16):

As far as I see no-one has mentioned temporal coupling yet, so here it is.

The second one (which returns void) has this [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Consider the following constructor code:

```
createMonsters();
...
doSomethingWithMonsters();
```

A maintainer easily could mix up the order of the called methods which breaks your class and might turn out only at runtime. It's not possible the following:

```
Monster[,] monsters = createMonsters();
...
doSomethingWithMonsters(monsters);
```

Changing the order of the two methods simply would not compile.

Another advantage of the first one is that your field could be `final` (or readonly, I'm not too familiar with C# but I guess it has something like that). The following constructor code also does not compile in Java if the `monsters` field is `final`:

```
doSomethingWithMonsters(monsters);
monsters = createMonsters();
```

Furthermore, having the array return value makes the code easier to read. It's obvious from the signature what the method does, readers don't have to check the method body to figure out its side-effects. Finally, you could call `createMonsters()` from other methods without side-effects.

Anyway, having the separate factory class (as a constructor parameter) looks even better, it's less coupled, +1 to Simon.

See also: *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *G31: Hidden Temporal Couplings*, p302

Comment: Yep, temporal coupling is the first thing that went through my mind when I read that question. This is a beautiful case for this.

Answer (score 11):

**It depends**

I personally find a method that returns it more flexible and more of a separation-of-concerns approach. And by doing so, you could even move the method into another class, such as a `Factory` class that perhaps can provide you with other monster arrays.

However, it is perfectly reasonable to use a method that returns `void` if:

- The reason for why you have this method in the first place is that you want to extract some code in your constructor into it's own method
- Your `myMonsterArray` is in a way "tightly coupled" with your class (i.e. it wouldn't make much sense to have the monster array without also having your class - think of a 8x8 chess grid without *the chess game itself* for example)

In the end, which way you choose is up to you.

#### Other comments

Instead of numbering your `SpriteFactory.getMonster1Sprite()` methods, use `SpriteFactory.getMonsterSprite(1)`, this would allow you to write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 6; a++)
    {
        myMonsterArray[a, i] = new Monster(SpriteFactory.getMonsterSprite(a % 3));
    }
}
```

**Magic numbers:** Instead of using `8` and `6` (and perhaps even `3`) in the double-loop above, retreive the length of your array with `myMonsterArray.GetLength(0)` and `myMonsterArray.GetLength(1)`.

Comment: The length of an array is retrieved with `myArray.Length` ...or did you think it was Java? ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug No, I'm aware it's C#. `GetLength` is what [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.array.getlength) and also what I used in [my C# Sudoku Solver](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37448/sudokusharp-solver-with-advanced-features) - have I missed anything?

Comment: Nevermind, brainfart. Length wouldn't be useful for multidimentional arrays.. catxh you in chat later! :)

Comment: An additional reason, related to the ones you cite, for preferring the version that returns the values: you could then extract an abstract superclass and defer creating the values to the subclass, and have the resulting variable remain private rather than needing to be changed to protected.  A simpler variant of the Factory version you suggest.

Answer (score 8):

Consider it is just an initializer and will only be used this once, there is no need to make it explicitly return the data when you can just set it directly.

Therefore the second approach would be my approach as well.

## Naming

Method names are UpperCamelCase in C# so this

```
createMonsters
```

should become

```
CreateMonsters
```

## Indices

You have your indices swapped: you define it as `[8, 6]` but you use it as `[6, 8]` which will lead to `IndexOutOfRangeExceptions`

Answer (score 5):

I would pick the method where you return an array of objects, because that makes it easier to unit test that method should you feel the need.

Comment: `private` methods should not be unit tested considering they are not a part of the exposed API and thus, by definition, their internal definition is not reliable.

Comment: Many frameworks provide the ability to test private methods. Unit testing is usually done by the developers who are well aware of the functionality. In my opinion unit testing of private members will help to improve the quality.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: The first approach is better, pure functions are easier to understand.

I would personally go with the first approach. As a general rule I prefer pure functions. While in this case I don't think it would make much difference, I have very rarely ever found that I was happier with a mutating function like this. I think pure functions are much easier to reason about, and reduce complexity. In general the creation of the object is best left to the function while the assignment should be left to the constructor.

As with all code, if there was a single rule that could be easily applied, we wouldn't need programmers, as computers already excel at applying basic rules. What makes a programmer valuable is that there are many tools/patterns that can be applied, and they always have various trade offs. Our job is to understand where the tools/patterns give good value and apply them intelligently.