# Create a LINQ Killer Sudoku Cage Solver

Tags: c#, linq, sudoku

When playing Killer Sudoku I find myself repeatedly writing stuff like this:

```
12/3
921
831
741
732
651
642
543
```

and then crossing out the combinations that include say 9, 7, and 6

IE I need a list of any 3 digits between 1 and 9 that add up to 12, excluding 9, 7, and 6 because they are already in the house.

So I wrote a Linq query to run in LinqPad that does this. However its pretty specific. Here is the implementation for 3 numbers:

```
var num=3;
var target=12;
var exceptions=new List<int>{9,7,6};

var List1 = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
var List2 = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
var List3 = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

// Make a Cartesian join of the three lists
// Filter out the stuff that we want
// Sort the result from highest to lowest
var combo = (from l1 in List1
        from l2 in List2
        from l3 in List3        // Cartesian product    
        where l1 > l2 && l2 > l3    // exclude duplicates
        && l1 + l2 + l3 == target   // add up to the target 
        && !exceptions.Contains(l1) // exclude exceptions
        && !exceptions.Contains(l2)
        && !exceptions.Contains(l3)
        select new List<int>{l1, l2, l3})                       
        .OrderByDescending (c =>c[0] ) 
        .ThenByDescending (d => d[1])
        .ThenByDescending (e => e[2]);

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}/{1}", target, num));
foreach(var item in combo){ 
for (var i=0; i< num;i++){
    Console.Write(item[i]);
}       
Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.Write("excluding");
foreach(var i in exceptions){
    Console.Write(string.Format(" {0} ",i));
}
```

I have found it pretty useful but is there a better and more general way of implementing this?

Comment: TIL `Console.Write` works in LinqPad, thanks

Comment: Related if you want to take it a step further later on: [My Sudoku solver in C#](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37448/sudokusharp-solver-with-advanced-features) (You make me want to add functionality for solving Killer Sudoku's with it actually)

Answer (score 1):

### Naming

Use `camelCase` for local variable names. And, use a meaningful name if *possible*.

```
//var List1 = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
var validNumbers = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

Use pluralized noun for variable of collection type.

```
//var combo = ... /*combo contains all possible combinations, not just one*/
var combos
```

### Code

- You don't need to enumerate the numbers 1 to 9. A `Enumerable.Range` will do the job.
- The chain of `!exceptions.Contains(x)` is rather inefficient and redundant. You can avoid them by removing the exceptions from the start with `IEnumerable.Except`.
- You can reuse the same list in your LINQ.
- You can reuse the same name for your lambdas given they are not within the same parentheses.  (Not really a big problem)

Result :

```
var validNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).Except(exceptions);
var combos = (from a in validNumbers
              from b in validNumbers
              from b in validNumbers       // Cartesian product    
              where a > b && b > c &&      // exclude duplicates
                    a + b + c == target    // add up to the target 
              select new List<int>{ a, b , c})
             .OrderByDescending(x => x[0]) 
             .ThenByDescending(x => x[1])
             .ThenByDescending(x => x[2]);
```

---

In the last 2 blocks of the code, `Console.Write` was repeatedly called within the `for loop`. You can join them together with `String.Join` before printing it to the console.

Results :

```
foreach(var item in combos)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", item));

Console.Write("excluding " + string.Join(" ", exceptions));
```

---

### Final Code

This can be directly copied to LinqPad and ran.

```
void Main()
{
    string buffer;
    int target, elementCount;

    //get target
    Console.WriteLine(">> Target is ..?");

    while(!int.TryParse(buffer = Console.ReadLine(), out target))
        Console.WriteLine("\tInvalid input : {0}", buffer);
    Console.WriteLine(target);

    //get elementCount
    Console.WriteLine(">> Number of elements is ..?");

    while(!int.TryParse(buffer = Console.ReadLine(), out elementCount) ||
          1 > elementCount || elementCount > 6)
        Console.WriteLine("\tInvalid input : {0}", buffer);
    Console.WriteLine(elementCount);
    Console.WriteLine(/*Empty Line*/);

    //get exceptions
    var validNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 9);
    IEnumerable<int?> exceptions;
    Console.WriteLine(">> Exceptions are ..? (separated with comma like : 1,2,3)");

    while(!TryParseExceptions(buffer = Console.ReadLine(), out exceptions))
        Console.WriteLine("\tInvalid input : {0}", buffer);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", exceptions.OrderBy(x => x)));

    Console.WriteLine(/*Empty Line*/);
    CalculateCombinations(target, elementCount, exceptions.Select(e => e.Value).Distinct());
}

int? ToNullableInt(string value)
{
    int number;
    return int.TryParse(value.Trim(), out number) ? (int?)number : null;
}
bool TryParseExceptions(string value, out IEnumerable<int?> exceptions)
{
    //const int MinValue = 1, MaxValue = 9;
    exceptions = value == ""
        ? Enumerable.Empty<int?>()
        : value.Split(',').Select(ToNullableInt);

    return exceptions.All(e => e.HasValue && (1 <= e.Value && e.Value <= 9)); //less verbose but magical...
    //return exceptions.All(e => e.HasValue && (MinValue <= e.Value && e.Value <= MaxValue));
}

// Define other methods and classes here
void CalculateCombinations(int target, int elementCount, IEnumerable<int> exceptions)
{
    var validNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).Except(exceptions);

    // Make a Cartesian join of the three lists
    // Filter out the stuff that we want
    // Sort the result from highest to lowest
    var combos = validNumbers.CartesianProduct(elementCount)     // Cartesian product 
                            .Where(x => x.GreaterThanNext() &&   // exclude duplicates
                                        x.Sum(y => y) == target) // add up to the target 
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.First());  // sort from the 1st number to...

    for(int i = 1; i < elementCount; i++)
    {
                    ///i would be incremented when the ienumerable unfolds
        var index = i;
        combos = combos.ThenByDescending(x => x.ElementAt(index));   // ... the [n]th
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}/{1}", target, elementCount));

    foreach(var item in combos)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", item));

    Console.Write("excluding : " + string.Join(" ", exceptions.OrderBy(x => x)));
}

//credit : http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/
//slightly altered to reuse the same sequence

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int repeat) 
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> result =  new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };

        for(int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
        { 
            // don't close over the loop variable (fixed in C# 5 BTW)
            var s = sequence; 
            // recursive case: use SelectMany to build 
            // the new product out of the old one 
            result = from seq in result 
                    from item in s 
                    select seq.Concat(new[] {item}); 
        }

        return result; 
    }

    public static bool GreaterThanNext(this IEnumerable<int> sequence)
    {
        if (sequence.Count() < 2) return true;

        var previous = int.MaxValue;
        foreach(var item in sequence)
            if(previous <= item)
                return false;
            else previous = item;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Example of result :

```
>> Target is ..?
25
>> Number of elements is ..?
4

>> Exceptions are ..? (separated with comma like : 1,2,3)
1

25/4
9862
9853
9763
9754
8764
excluding : 1
```

Comment: Cool! You are totally right (Enumerable.Range(1,9)) and the Console.Write(...).

It took me so long to find a solution to a single instance that I just got sloppy.

The first enlightenment was  a > b && b > c which removes a lot of the duplicates.

The next issue is how to make num a variable.

For me num=2 I can do in my head. 

num=3 and num=4 require me to write stuff down and then strike stuff out as per the original question.

How do we create a single method that accepts num, target, and exclusions as arguments?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly `num` does? Is it used for 4x4x4 sudoku map?

Comment: `num` is because in killer there are additional groups of numbers on top of the rows, columns, and blocks of a basic sudoku. The additional groups can be any connected set of cells, and each provides two constraints: a total of the values in the cells which make up the group, and a guarantee that said values are distinct. So a 9x9 killer can have some additional groups of 1 element, some of 3, some of 6, etc.

Comment: So `num` affects the number of these `l1` `l2` `l3`?

Comment: Updated my answer to accept `num` as a variable

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the number of elements variable, you're probably going to have to go beyond a single Linq expression. This is basically an adaptation of the standard problem of finding partitions of an integer, but you have addition constraints: no repetition, no use of the excluded values, and no exceeding `9`.

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GenerateCage(int num, int target, params int[] excluded)
{
    return GenerateCageInner(num, target, 1, 9, new HashSet<int>(excluded));
}

private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GenerateCageInner(int num, int target, int min, int max, HashSet<int> excluded)
{
    // Base case
    if (num == 0)
    {
        if (target == 0) yield return new int[0];
        yield break;
    }

    // Recursive case
    for (int i = min; i <= max && i <= target; i++)
    {
         if (excluded.Contains(i)) continue;

         foreach (var subsoln in GenerateCageInner(num - 1, target - 1, min + 1, max, excluded))
         {
             var soln = new List<int>();
             soln.Add(i);
             soln.AddRange(subsoln);
             yield return soln;
         }
    }
}
```

This code aims to be simple over being efficient, although there are some efficiency considerations. It uses a `HashSet` for testing membership of the excluded set rather than iterating through it, and it uses `min` to avoid duplicates. The next efficiency complication to add would be using `num` and `min` to quick-reject cases where we will certainly exceed `target`.