# Verification of Sudoku boards

Tags: matlab, sudoku

A valid Sudoku board has the following properties

- The board must be square (n-by-n). Let `m = sqrt(n)`
- All rows must contain the numbers 1-n
- All columns must contain the numbers 1-n
- All nine m-by-m blocks must contain all numbers 1-n

The following MATLAB code verifies a Sudoku board of arbitrary sizes (where `n` is a square number):

```matlab
function correct_board = sudoku_checker(board)

correct_board = true;
[rows, cols] = size(board);
correct_size = (rows == cols) && mod(sqrt(rows),1) == 0;
if correct_size == false
    disp('The board is not square')
    correct_board = false
else
    disp('The board is square')
    for ii = 1:rows
        if ~(isequal(unique(board(:,ii)), (1:rows)') && isequal(unique(board(ii,:)), (1:rows)))
            disp(['Numbers ' num2str(1) '-' num2str(rows) ' are not present in all rows or columns'])
            correct_board = false;
            return
        end
    end
    disp(['Numbers ' num2str(1), '-' num2str(rows) ' are present in all rows and columns'])

    cell_blocks = mat2cell(board, repmat(sqrt(rows),sqrt(rows),1),repmat(sqrt(rows),sqrt(rows),1));
    blocks_ok = all(arrayfun(@(x) isequal(unique(cell_blocks{x}),(1:rows)'), 1:rows));
    if blocks_ok == true
        disp(['All blocks are OK'])
    else
        disp(['All blocks are not OK'])
        correct_board = false;
        return;
    end
    disp('Board is OK')
end
end
```

A valid board will give the following output:

```
sudoku_checker(board)
The board is square
Numbers 1-9 are present in all rows and columns
All blocks are OK
Board is OK
```

An incorrect board will give an output like this (dependent on which condition that fails):

```
sudoku_checker(board)
The board is square
Numbers 1-4 are present in all rows and columns
All blocks are not OK
```

I'm wondering if there are ways to improve this code. I'm looking for improvements in performance and algorithm, as well as improvement in coding style etc.

Can I simplify any expressions? Remove some boolean operators?

Comment: FWIW, I've seen 6x6 Sudoku boards. The blocks are 2x3.

Comment: Yea, there are all kinds of more complex Sudoku boards out there. One could try to [solve them all](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/37448/52915), but you got to start somewhere. It's a good idea to keep modularity in mind if you intend to solve the complex ones later as well though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A few general things first:**

`'` is the [conjugate transpose](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html), not the [transpose](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html). These are the same for real values, but will behave differently when you have complex values. To avoid confusion, it is recommended that you always use `.'` when transposing a matrix, even if it's real.

---

You're using both `disp('text')` and `disp('[text]')`. The first one works for plain strings, while the other must be used when concatenating strings and numbers. I suggest you either use brackets on all calls to `disp`, or skip the brackets for all calls to `disp` where the string is plain text. Consistency is always nice.

---

**Variable names:**

The variable names are well chosen and descriptive. One minor comment is that you're using `correct_size` and `correct_board`, but `blocks_ok`. `correct_blocks` is probably a better word here, to keep consistency.

---

**Frequently used variables:**

There are a few variables that are used over and over again. You should declare the following variables outside the loop:

```
sq_rows = sqrt(rows); 
values= 1:rows;
```

---

**Avoid the loop and calls to `unique` by sorting the board by rows and columns:**

You can avoid the loops by sorting all columns of the regular board, and the board when it's transposed, instead of checking for unique values.

```
isequal(sort(board), sort(board.'), repmat(values.',1, rows))
```

`repmat(values.',1,rows)` produces a matrix looking like this:

```
1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3
4     4     4     4
```

---

**Alternatives to `repmat(sqrt(rows),sqrt(rows),1)`:**

Using `mat2cell` to create `cell_blocks` is good, but the expression can be simplifed using the new pre-defined variables. There are some alternatives to `repmat(sqrt(rows),sqrt(rows),1)` that are more readable, such as:

```
ones(sq_rows,1) * sq_rows;
zeros(sq_rows,1) + sq_rows;
```

[`repelem`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) is an option if you're using MATLAB version R2015a or newer.

---

**Use `cellfun` when you're working with cells, and `arrayfun` when you are working with other "stuff".**

Since `cell_blocks` is a cell array, you can use [`cellfun`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
all(cellfun(@(x) isequal(unique(x),values.'), cell_blocks))
```

---

**Simplifying the disp-calls:**

You know that the first number in the sequence is 1, so you can simplify the two `disp`-calls in the middle:

```
disp(['Numbers 1-' num2str(rows) ' are present in all rows and columns'])
```

---

I believe you're missing a `break` after checking the size of the board (first if).

---

**Comments!**

I suggest you use a lot more comments! Explain what the different parts of your code do.